# Getting the last day of an already existing date in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssms

I have a table with a list of clients, with a column that shows the date their accounts were created. I want to make the last day of this date. I tried using the EOMONTH function, but it does not work.

For instance, if client 1 came on January 6th, and client 2 came on February 6th of this year, I want it to show 31-01-2018 and 28-02-2018.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: And how does `eomonth()` not work?  That is exactly what the function does.

Comment: How did you use the `EOMONTH` function?

Comment: my version of SSMS does not support eomonth :(

Comment: Have a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/490579bc-966a-4f16-8ad7-69c55dbe3afe/emonth-equivalent-function-in-sql-2008), several options are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon is right, I have tried `EOMONTH` for your given data and it returns perfect value look at below, in second parameter you have to pass value as per requirement if you pass value as `1` it will give you last date of next month i.e Jan+1=Feb

```
 DECLARE @myDate Datetime='06-Jan-2018'
 SELECT EOMONTH(@myDate,0) AS MyDate
```

If your version not support the EOMONTH function then try below query:

```
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@myDate)+1,0)) AS DATE)
```

Output:

[image]